# Ativar o Token para usar o discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Estou tentando criar um Bot do discord, porém, ao rodar o código, dá um erro: discord.client: logging in using static token

Código:

```
    import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f'Message from {message.author}: {message.content}')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('meu token está aqui')
```

Não estou entendendo o motivo disso sendo que eu pego o token exatamente onde é para ser pego

Comment: Normalmente tokens OAuth tem um token estático, que é usado para gerar outros dois tokens: o refreshToken e o authToken. Tente ler a documentação do Discord pra entender melhor como deve ser feito o processo de autenticação.

Answer (score -1):

Esse erro é gerado ao utilizar o token incorreto, ou até mesmo utilizar algo que não seja o token do seu bot.

Para gerar o token correto que deve ser utilizado para logar com seu bot, vá para o portal de desenvolvimento do discord, entre na sua aplicação, acesse a aba "Bot" no menu lateral esquerdo e gere seu token no campo abaixo do nome de seu BOT.

Tenha em mente que só poderá ver ele novamente nessa página caso resete o token.

[image: Imagem ilustrando o local correto para gerar seu token. Em amarelo, a aba do menu lateral que deve ser acessada. Em vermelho, o lugar que consegue encontrar seu token dentro dessa aba.]